# Stack Overflow is no longer accepting questions from my account. How should I go about fixing my existing questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, post-ban

As the title states. I've been banned from asking any more questions. Previously, my questions have been downvoted and I've recently tried to improve the quality of my questions. My most recent question is an example. I put more effort into it and made it fairly detailed and even included some stuff of what I tried to fix my problem and even some output from `gdb`. However, it's still getting downvotes. At this point, I'm not sure what I did wrong. As far as I knew my most recent question was what Stack Overflow wants, but it has unfortunately caused my account to be banned.

What was wrong with the question, and how can I go about fixing it and my other questions in order to lift this ban?

This is the specific question I was referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254806/accessing-a-struct-member-using-a-pointer-to-a-pointer

Some of my other questions have also been downvoted but after hearing what the community has to say about this one, I can generalize to my other questions.

Comment: This question was already asked like *integer overflow* times; http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997

Comment: I understand that but like my post said, I honestly thought my most recent question was up to stackoverflow standards. So I'm looking to see what is wrong with it in particular and hopefully I can generalise that to my other questions.

Comment: Let's be clear:  it wouldn't be just the *one* question that's got you blocked from asking any more.

Comment: FWIW, you are not currently blocked.

Comment: Add a link to the question you are referring to, and add a tag `specific-question` here so we can take a look. That way you may get some useful advice. (This may include the Meta Effect deciding the question is not *too* bad, or it got better after you following that advice - and thus gain some votes.)

Comment: @Peter: care to add a link to this one question? Else the tag makes no sense :P  I believe that is what OP is asking - hopefully there is only one candidate. It needs the plural removed from the title though.